# Can we use one stream to access different file contents in Java

Tags: java, java-io

Consider this situation,
I have 2 text files namely file1.txt and file2.txt

Can I use just one FileInputStream object to access data of both the files? Rather than declaring 2 separate FileInputStream objects each for a file?

Comment: Even if it were possible (it's not), why would you want to? Do you think it would be more efficient somehow?

Comment: @Kayaman Thanks for the answer though. I wanted to save space on creating an extra object for each file.

Comment: It would only matter if you forgot to close the stream (leaking resources), or if you had hundreds of streams open at the same time (which might hit some operating system limits). There's no need to be scared of creating "extra objects". There are thousands and thousands of objects in play in the background, so it usually doesn't make much of a difference whether you create one or ten or a thousand objects.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. An instance of `FileInputStream` can only be used once with one file.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer! Also I had one more question. Can we then use single BufferedInputStream object associated with multiple FileInputStream objects?

Comment: The answer is the same: a `BufferedInputStream` instance can only be used once.